# Два div-a рядом, проблемы с расположением

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Хочу, чтобы два блока располагались рядом. Возможно проблема в том, что у меня есть цикл, организованный с помощью php, заполняющий список...
Пробовал `style="float:left;"` — не помогает.

код:

```
<h3>Info offer</h3><br/>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <?php foreach($data as $item) { ?>
        <li class="list-group-item active"></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">№ предложения: <?=$item['id']?></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Name company: <?=$item['name_company']?></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Place car: <?=$item['place_car']?></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Contact Email: <?=$item['cont_email']?></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Contact phone: <?=$item['cont_phone']?></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Start point: <?=$item['start_p']?></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Finish point: <?=$item['finish_p']?></li>
        <LI style='color:white; '></LI>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

стили взяты из шаблона с bootstrap-a, css:

```
.list-group {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.list-group-item {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.list-group-item > .badge {
    float: right;
}

.list-group-item > .badge + .badge {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
}
```

Comment: Какие два блока должны располагаться рядом?

Comment: блок <div class="col-sm-4">. при выполнении , (допустим в базе 2 записи), блок повторяется и располагается под первым, а надо что б он расположился рядом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ты хочешь чтобы блок col-sm-4 генерился по горизонтали , то добавь ему класс cf и следующий код.

```
.col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
    float: left;
}
.cf:after {
   content: "";
   clear: both;
   display: block;
}
```

И тогда каждый раз когда будет генерироваться болк col-sm-4 он будет плавать на предыдущий. После плавающих блоков нужно всегда делать очитску , чтобы они вели себя адекватно.